# Cloudformation S3 bucket principal for Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a Yaml template for cloudfront distribution on S3 bucket.
I'm stuck on how to add `principal` on `BucketPolicy`.

I want to know how to replace the `XXXXXXXXXXX` on CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX in principal for a cloudfront that will be generate by deploying the template.

Also is there a way to add the html, css sync procedure (which I'm doing through aws cli now) on yaml template?

Please let me know.
TIA

```
 AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
 Resources:
   Bucket:
     Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
     Properties:
       BucketName: pridesys.webbucket
       AccessControl: Private 
       WebsiteConfiguration:
         IndexDocument: index.html

   BucketPolicy:
     Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
     Properties:
       Bucket: !Ref Bucket
       PolicyDocument:
         Id: ReportPolicy
         Version: "2012-10-17"
         Statement:
           - Sid: "1"
             Effect: Allow
             Action: "s3:GetObject"
             Principal:
               AWS: "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
             Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref Bucket, '/*']]

   Distro:
     Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
     Properties:
       DistributionConfig:
         Origins:
           - DomainName: !GetAtt Bucket.DomainName
             Id: foo
             S3OriginConfig: {}
          Enabled: True
         DefaultRootObject: index.html
         DefaultCacheBehavior:
           ForwardedValues:
             QueryString: False
           TargetOriginId: foo
           ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Jens !!

Your solution was a big help. I was getting TargetOriginId & ForwarededValues error while trying to deploy your template.

This is what worked for me -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  WebUIBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  CloudFrontOriginIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
    Comment: "origin identity"
  WebUIPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties: 
      Bucket:
        Ref: WebUIBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser:
                Fn::GetAtt: [ CloudFrontOriginIdentity , S3CanonicalUserId ]
            Action: "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: !Sub "${WebUIBucket.Arn}/*"
  WebpageCDN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Sub "${WebUIBucket}.s3.amazonaws.com"
            Id: webpage
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginIdentity}"
        Enabled: True
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: False
          TargetOriginId: webpage
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

Comment: I came here looking for how to do this with JSON and found this useful. For anyone interested the JSON equivalent is: `"Principal": { "CanonicalUser": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "CloudFrontOriginIdentity", "S3CanonicalUserId" ] } }`

Answer (score 19):

Here is a valid sample of an S3 origin identity configuration for CloudFront:

```
  WebUIBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  CloudFrontOriginIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: "origin identity"
  WebUIPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties: 
      Bucket:
        Ref: WebUIBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser:
                Fn::GetAtt: [ CloudFrontOriginIdentity , S3CanonicalUserId ]
            Action: "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: !Sub "${WebUIBucket.Arn}/*"
  WebpageCDN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Sub "${WebUIBucket}.s3.amazonaws.com"
            Id: webpage
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginIdentity}"
```

As for the syncing your assets into the S3 bucket, that cannot be provided with CloudFormation functionality. You either have to implement a CustomResource or keep using the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to have `S3 origin Access Identity` setup, and use the `!GetAtt S3CanonicalUserId`

Here is my code and it works

```
S3CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties: 
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: A comment to describe the origin access identity. The comment cannot be longer than 128 characters.
    
StagingCloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !GetAtt myS3bucket.DomainName
          Id: !Ref myS3bucket
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: !Join ['', ['origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref S3CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity]]

myS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref myS3bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: myS3bucketPolicy
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid:  PutObjectAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              CanonicalUser:
                Fn::GetAtt: [ S3CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity, S3CanonicalUserId ]
            Action: 
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource: !Join 
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - !Ref myS3bucket
                - /*
```